# Ext.grid.column.Check click event to the CheckBox itself not the whole cell area

Tags: extjs, extjs4

Is there any to way to restrict check column action to only check box and restrict to the cell area. sample code for check column which i have copied from docs.

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    fields: ['name', 'email', 'phone', 'active'],
    data: [{
        name: 'Lisa',
        email: 'lisa@simpsons.com',
        phone: '555-111-1224',
        active: true
    }, {
        name: 'Bart',
        email: 'bart@simpsons.com',
        phone: '555-222-1234',
        active: true
    }, {
        name: 'Homer',
        email: 'homer@simpsons.com',
        phone: '555-222-1244',
        active: false
    }, {
        name: 'Marge',
        email: 'marge@simpsons.com',
        phone: '555-222-1254',
        active: true
    }]
 });

Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    title: 'Simpsons',
    height: 200,
    width: 400,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    store: store,
    columns: [{
        text: 'Name',
        dataIndex: 'name'
    }, {
        text: 'Email',
        dataIndex: 'email',
        flex: 1
    }, {
        text: 'Phone',
        dataIndex: 'phone'
    }, {
        xtype: 'checkcolumn',
        text: 'Active',
        dataIndex: 'active'
    }]
});
```

Kindly help me on this.

Comment: you want to select the check box without selecting the row?

Comment: You can only write your own class. Have you looked at the source code.

Comment: What version of ExtJS are you using? I mean the full version (ie 4.1.1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution will work on every version of ExtJS from 4.2.0 to 4.2.6.

```
Ext.define('CheckColumn', {
    override: 'Ext.grid.column.' + (!!Ext.grid.column.Check ? 'Check': 'CheckColumn'),
    processEvent: function(type, view, cell, recordIndex, cellIndex, e, record, row) {
        var me = this,
            key = type === 'keydown' && e.getKey(),
            mousedown = type == 'mousedown';

        if (mousedown && !Ext.fly(e.getTarget()).hasCls('x-grid-checkcolumn')) {
            return !me.stopSelection;
        }

        me.callParent([type, view, cell, recordIndex, cellIndex, e, record, row]);
    }
});
```

Comment: based on your example I have applied the above fix in beforecheckchange.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Guiherme lopes answer I have applied the fix in beforecheckchange.

```
 beforecheckchange: function(me , rowIndex , checked , record , e , eOpts){
           if(!Ext.fly(e.getTarget()).hasCls('x-grid-checkcolumn')){
              return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
```